# Reading filename from command line in assembly

Tags: parameters, command, line, x86-16, dosbox

I was making an assembly program (Intel 8086, DosBox) which is reading from other file. 
Inside of my asm code I have it's name in

```
File db 'myFile.FIL',0
```

and everything i have to do to read from that file is to compile and run my project.exe. But now i would like to set file name as command line parameter.
For example if i'll write:

`project.exe file2.fil` and hit Enter

I want to read from "file2.fil" instead of "myFile.FIL"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> project.exe file2.fil and hit Enter

You will find the name "file2.fil" as part of the commandline stored in the ProgramSegmentPrefix (PSP).

When your program starts the `DS` segment register points at the 256 bytes PSP and the commandline starts at offset 128 within this PSP.

The first byte (at offset 128) tells you the length of the text that follows. The text itself is terminated by a carriage return code (13) but this is not included in the forementioned length.
The first character of the text (at offset 129) is mostly a space character (32), so don't include it when passing a zero-terminated string to the DOS api!